# ¿Como validar datos? sea único por producto en un Datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

Tengo un pequeño problema estoy intentando validar dos datos ingresados en un DataGridview les explico

Si yo ingreso por ejemplo

```
Código   | producto         | marca         | presentación | tipo
---------|------------------|---------------|--------------|-------
0000001  | Formula 12-24-12 | Fertilizantes | 100          | polvo
0000002  | Formula 12-24-12 | Fertilizantes | 45           | polvo
```

Hasta aquí correcto, porque puede haber **mismos productos con diferente presentación**. pero **no puede haber productos con la misma presentación** seria ilógico creo yo, y no se si me explico.

Asi es como estoy intentando validar esa parte.

```
bool Existe = dgv_producto.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Any(y => Convert.ToString(y.Cells[0].Value) == Convert.ToString(y.Cells[4].Value));

if (Existe)
{
     MessageBox.Show("No puede agregar el mismo producto con una misma presentacion ", "Producto ya existe", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
     return;
}
```

Comment: ¿Como agregas filas al grid? manualmente? por datasource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Así lo haría yo:

Primero, la fuente de datos para el datagridview la crearía usando una BindingList:

```
private readonly BindingList<Producto> productos = new BindingList<Producto>();
```

Podrías utilizar una lista normal, pero cuando agregues elementos a la lista el datagridview no se actualizaría, con la BindingList si se actualiza.

Producto es una clase que contiene los datos que capturas como propiedades, entre ellas una propiedad llamada Presentacion:

```
public class Producto
{
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Producto { get; set; }
    public string Marca { get; set; }
    public string Presentacion { get; set; }} // <= esta propiedad
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

Luego enlazaría la bindinglist al dgv:

```
this.dgv_Producto.DataSource = productos;
```

Y cada que quiera agregar un producto validaria que no exista en la lista:

```
if (productos.Exists(x => x.Presentacion == nuevapresentacion)
{
    // aqui avisas al usuario
}
else
{
    productos.Add(/* aquí va el producto a insertar*/);
}
```

Donde "nuevapresentacion" contiene la presentación capturada.

Incluso puedes hacer un método que te regrese false si no se agregó el producto:

```
private bool AgregaProducto(Producto producto)
{
     if (productos.Exists(x => x.Presentacion == producto.Presentacion)
     {
         return false;
     }

     productos.Add(producto);
     return true;
}
```

Y ya nada mas haces eso:

```
var productoagregar = new Producto();
// aquí pasas la información capturada al objeto productoagregar
productoagregar.Codigo = txtCodigo.Text;
productoagregar.Producto = txtProducto.Text;
// etc...
// y con el objeto creado 
if(!AgregaProducto(productoagregar)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No puede agregar el mismo producto con una misma presentacion ", "Producto ya existe", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```